# Function that returns a string of digits that represent the base b representation of n in python

Tags: python, int, radix

I have:

```
def d2x(n, b):
    res = ""
    while n != 0 :
        res = n % b + res
        n = n / b
    return res
```

Example outputs:

```
d2x(10,2)
    '1010' 
d2x(10,3)
    '101'
d2x(10,8)
    '12'
```

I'm honestly lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your method should concatenate chars, otherwise it will just add in base 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work upto base 16....

```
#convert base 10 to any base between 2 and 16
def convBase(n, base):
    charSeq = '0123456789ABCDEF'
    if n < base:
        return charSeq[n]
    else:
        return convBase(n//base, base) + charSeq[n%base]

#print convBase(10,16)
```

Comment: Thank you. I just have one question: in the last return, what is the base after the comma do?

Comment: its just a way to pass base (b/w 2 to 16) without having to declare it as a global...the base in general is used to index a string character as depicted by charSeq...its not modified anywhere in the recursive/or return code...